# External Storage directory strange bug?

Tags: android, sd-card

The following code works fine on Galaxy S4 but I have received bug report from a note 3 device saying that "null pointer exception at line #4367"

I can't understand that for what reason it happens since the for loop is tested with fileArray.length;

I may be wrong; please give some suggestion about this issue.

Thank you.

[image]

```
                    File fileArray[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);      

                    String fileArayAsPathArray[] = new String[fileArray.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++){
                       fileArayAsPathArray[i] = fileArray[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The file array itself must have a null inside of it at some legal index.  You'll need to code around it.  Something like:

```
List<String> fileArayAsPathList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++){
    if(fileArray[i] != null){
        fileArayAsPathList.add( fileArray[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation of getExternalFilesDirs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)):

> Returned paths may be null if a storage device is unavailable.

So you should check for null:

```
File fileArray[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);      

if (filesArray != null) {
    String fileArayAsPathArray[] = new String[fileArray.length];
    for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++) {
        if(fileArray[i] != null) {
            fileArayAsPathArray[i] = fileArray[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
}
```